# sqlite group by with multiple sorts

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5
```

- Column1 is a unique integer, but not necessarily sorted.
- Column2 is an integer that may have repeated values in the column.
- Column3 is an integer that I need to sort on 3rd.
- Column4 is an integer that I need to sort on 1st.
- Column5 is an integer that I need to sort on 2nd.

How can I group my Column2, and maintain the sort order that I want?

Comment: Do you have a clear understanding of the group by clause? What is your expected result? Aren't you looking for DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YOURTABLE A,
(
SELECT Column2
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY Column2
) B
WHERE A.Column2=B.Column2
ORDER BY A.Column4,A.Column5,A.Column3;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're actually looking for a distinct instead of a group by (you haven't specified any aggregate function). So, I understand you want to remove duplicates and order the results:

```
select distinct Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 from table
order by Column4, Column5, Column6
```

Please, provide more detail and your expected results.

Comment: I want Column2 to be distinct, but when I go distinct on it it blows away my sorts.

Comment: So the results are a table with the number of distinct values from column2, but they're in the order I need.